# Is this "decomposition" just the Taylor expansion?

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose $a=a(\vec{x},t)$ is a function of coordinates $\vec{x}$ and time $t$. Moreoever, let the time derivative be of the form $\dot{a}=w(a,\nabla a,\Delta a)$, where $w$ is some function. Additionally, it is assumed that spatial interactions are local and the spatial variation of $a$ is slow

Then, it is said that one can

> "decompose the right-hand side in terms of $\nabla a$ and $\Delta a$, keeping only the first terms:
> $$
> \dot{a}=g(a)+A\nabla a+B (\nabla a)^2 + D\Delta a,
> $$
> where $A, B, D$ represent certain functions of $a$."

I am not sure if I do get the point: Where does this decomposition come from, isn't it just the Taylor expansion of $w$ around the point $(a,0,0)$ so that
\begin{align*}
g(a)&=w(a,0,0),\\
A&=\partial_y w(a,\nabla a,\Delta a),\\
B&=\frac{1}{2!}\partial_{yy}w(a,\nabla a,\Delta a),\\
D&=\partial_z w(a,\nabla a,\Delta a)?
\end{align*}

At least, it seems to me that the assumption that the spatial variation is slow means that both $\nabla a$ and $\Delta a$ are assumed to be close to $0$, respectively, and that the expression "in terms of $\nabla a$ and $\Delta a$" suggests to keep $a$ fix and to Taylor expand in $(a,0,0)$.

Comment: Notation suggestion: you may want to use "\nabla" for grad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. Here's some explanation for where the constants come from:

---

Let x = $[a,\nabla a, \Delta a]$. Let us do the Taylor expansion around $\hat{a} = [a,0,0]$
\begin{align}
\dot{a}&=w(x) = w(a,\nabla a,\Delta a)\\
w(x)&=w(\hat a) + D(w)^\top(x-\hat a) + o((x-\hat a)^\top H(w)(x-\hat a))\\
\end{align}
where $D(w)$ is the jacobian of w (at \hat a), and $H(w)$ is the hessian. $o(\cdot)$ indicates higher order terms that we will ignore.

\begin{align}
w(x)&\simeq w(\hat a) + \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial w}{\partial a}\\\frac{\partial w}{\partial \nabla a}\\\frac{\partial w}{\partial\Delta a}\end{bmatrix}^\top(x-\hat a)\\
w(x)&\simeq w(a,0,0) + \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial w}{\partial a}\\\frac{\partial w}{\partial \nabla a}\\\frac{\partial w}{\partial\Delta a}\end{bmatrix}^\top\begin{bmatrix}0\\\nabla a\\\Delta a\end{bmatrix}\\
&= w(a,0,0) + \frac{\partial w}{\partial \nabla a} \nabla a + \frac{\partial w}{\partial \Delta a} \Delta a\\
&= g(a)+A\nabla a+ D\Delta a
\end{align}

where $A = \frac{\partial w}{\partial \nabla a}$ and $D = \frac{\partial w}{\partial \Delta a}$. There is one term missing - coefficient B of $[\nabla a]^2$, but I only get that if I consider higher order terms, and the question only asks us to keep "the first terms".